# Is there any way to handle on going timer activity continuous using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following action in jQuery button:

```
this.$el.find(".pt_timer_button button").off("click").on("click", this.on_timer);
```

Where `this.on_timer` is refereed as below:

```
on_timer: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            if ($(e.target).hasClass("pt_timer_start")) {
                current_date = this.get_current_UTCDate();
                this.project_timesheet_db.set_current_timer_activity({date: current_date});
                this.start_interval();
                this.initialize_timer();
                // this.save_interval();
                this.$el.find(".pt_timer_start,.pt_timer_stop").toggleClass("o_hidden");
                // this.resume_interval();
            }
```

And  in the `else` part logic of **STOP** buttons is given.

Now i have variables that monitors the time difference between, when the timer was started and the current value of time.

The code is :

```
start_interval: function() {
            var timer_activity = this.project_timesheet_db.get_current_timer_activity();
            var self = this;
            var newDate = new Date();
                    var refrence_date = newDate.getUTCFullYear() +"-"+ (newDate.getUTCMonth()+1) +"-"+newDate.getUTCDate()+" "+_.str.sprintf("%02d", newDate.getUTCHours())+":"+_.str.sprintf("%02d", newDate.getUTCMinutes())+":"+_.str.sprintf("%02d", newDate.getUTCSeconds());
                    var diff_in_seconds = moment.duration(moment(refrence_date).diff(moment(current_date))).asSeconds();
                    var h = parseInt(diff_in_seconds / 3600) % 24;
                    var h_hour = $(this).find("span.hours").add();
                    var h_text = parseInt(h_hour.text());
                    var m = parseInt(diff_in_seconds / 60) % 60;
                    var m_minute = $(this).find("span.minutes").add();
                    var m_text = parseInt(m_minute.text());
                    var s = parseInt(diff_in_seconds % 60);
                    var s_second = $(this).find("span.seconds");
                    var s_text = parseInt(s_second.text(s));
                    console.log("current time:", h, m, s);
                    console.log("difference of time at every moment:", hour, minute, seconds);
                });
```

Now explaining the scenario:
In my Html page I am displaying the time difference which is **var s**, **var m** and **var k**.

Now if i am reloading / refreshing the page timer is automatically set to 00.
I want to put something like that if timer is in process than it does not require to press **START** button again, and it should be kept in continue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

If any specific details required , write in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a cookie with the start time, and state?

Maybe, when you start the interval, write a cookie that looks like this:

```
{"start":reference_date, "isRunning":1}
```

Then, on each interval, check the current state. When you stop, update the state.

Comment: Is it something is possible that to Store button(start) state ?

Comment: Yes,  you can store it in a cookie. In the example above, the isRunning property is meant to imply the start state of the button.